# Value of upvote in stack overflow

Tags: bug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does “Reputation” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)

I have been using stack overflow for a little while and whenever I got an upvote, it was valued 10 points.

Yesterday I've got an upvote worth only 9 points without any explanation or downvotes on that same answer. Why is that? Should I specify which question it was? Is there a difference on upvotes by question/tag/user or any other attributes and conditions?

Comment: An upvote is worth about 3.2 microcents.

Comment: Yay, that means only about 819,000 points to go until I get my first dollar! Jon Skeet is already halfway there....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can only get 200 rep/day by upvote + edit   so you have reached 200 rep cap

you earned 191 rep than got an up vote(on answer ) than you will get only remaining rep 9

[image]

Comment: it doesn't get clearer than this

Answer (score 8):

Congratulations, that's the first time you got to the 200 reputation points cap.

It's explained in [the FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) :

> You can earn a maximum of 200 reputation per day. Please note that
>   votes for posts marked “community wiki” do not generate any
>   reputation, while accepted answers and bounty awards are not subject
>   to the daily reputation limit.

Comment: So if I had 195 points and got an upvote it would only be worth 5 points?

Comment: Yes, and all the following upvotes you gain bring you no reputation. That means it's time to go outside a little :)

Comment: Yep. Otherwise you would hear of programmers dying while stack overflowing, as you hear about gamers in Korea...

Comment: There are plenty of other SE sites to gain rep on! ;-)